# WebDriver with Java code does NOT open Firefox and does nothing in Windows XP

Tags: firefox, selenium, windows-xp, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to run Selenium2 (known as WebDriver) with Java in Firefox. It does not even open the Firefox and throw any error in the console. It stays idle and does nothing..

I am using FF 13 beta
Selenium WebDriver 2.23.1(Latest)
Win XP

I also tried Downgrading FF version(Changed to 9), It didn't work, Updated WebDriver to Latest(2.23.1) from 2.22, It didn't work

When I run this code in InternetExplorer(8), It will open the browser but will not identify any element and test fails..

My code:

```
public class Selenium2Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code ? Only then we can say what is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Hari: I am trying to run the example code of webdriver and it is not working:

Comment: public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: @SoftwareTesing You can Edit your posts, you know... Also, are you absolutely sure it does nothing? Selenium creates a new Firefox profile every time it starts - that could take a considerable amount of time! Other than that - you'll need to debug the code to see where it hang.

Comment: @Slance: I get no response for a long time whenever i run the test(more than half an hour) and the FF profile also does not open, no error is shown in the console..

Comment: Now, the latest version is Selenium WebDriver 2.26.0

Comment: I think it's version incompatibility of FF and WebDriver. Now I'm using FF 17 and WebDriver 2.29.0 : it's working well. @SoftwareTesing: I think your code looks good...

Comment: Please try FF 16 or above with Selenium WebDriver 2.23.1 It might work

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error. Windows + FF 14.0 and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I've debugged the code and i checked that the Thread is stucked on class FirefoxBinary, inside the method

```
public void clean(FirefoxProfile profile, File profileDir) throws IOException
```

the profile.isRunning(profileDir) always returns true... that's why nothing happens...

```
    if (Platform.getCurrent().is(Platform.WINDOWS)) {
          while (profile.isRunning(profileDir)) {
            sleep(500);
          }

          do {
            sleep(500);
          } while (profile.isRunning(profileDir));
        }
```

Then i updated to 2.25 and it worked!

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>]
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

To open firefox you will have to use the selenium firefox driver.

Refer to this simple example at this link - [The 5 Minute Getting Started Guide](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)

Let me know if the firefox browser opens up after you initialize the firefox driver.

Comment: :I have initialized FF driver, it is not working..
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Try not to use the latest firefox version and also make sure you are using all the necessary jars required to run selenium. Check this link - http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Tried downgrading the FF Version also, didn't help and also all the necessary jar files are added, It works in IE

Comment: Can you tell me which all selenium jars you are using. Make sure you are using the Selenium Server Standalone jar - selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar

Comment: Yes I was using selenium-server-standlaone-2.22.jar and I updated it to latest2.23.1 and it is working fine now.. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old post, but if someone will be looking for an answer, this helped me in similar case:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(@"path\to\firefox.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary,profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to fix this issue :-

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    FiewfoxDriver fdr = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: While this code is useful, a few words of explanation would make it even more useful to future readers.